# DateTime conversion in Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to write a query who select all data who was created today.

Here is my request :

```
public List<Projet> GetEnvoiMailBienvenueProjet(Site site)
        {
            var res =
                _context.Projet.Where(
                    a =>
                        a.SiteId == site.SiteId && a.Client1.AdresseClient.EnvoiEmailBienvenue &&
                        a.Client1.AdresseClient.Email != null && a.Client1.AdresseClient.Email != "" &&
                        a.CreationDate.ToString("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") == DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"));
            return res.ToList();
        }
```

I handle this exception :

> {"Method 'System.String ToString (System.String)' does not support the
>   translation into SQL."}

I already try others possibility all time throw an exception like that.

Comment: Why are you converting the values to strings *at all*?

Comment: @JonSkeet i think he wants to ignore time

Comment: Use `DateTime.Today` if you want to strip the time part

Comment: @fubo: Yes, but that doesn't mean you need to use string conversions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you get rid of the string conversion entirely:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
var res =
        _context.Projet.Where(
            a => ... && a.CreationDate == today);
```

Or possibly (if `a.CreationDate` contains a time as well):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
var res =
        _context.Projet.Where(
            a => ... && a.CreationDate.Date == today);
```

You should only use string conversions (either parsing or formatting) when you're actually interested in the textual representation. Here, it seems that all you're really interested in is comparing the date components - and you definitely don't need string conversions for that.

Comment: Perfect ! I converted my date to string because she contains Time too. Thx a lot !

Comment: @user2621595: Right - my point is a broader one though. Not just here, but in general, try to avoid unnecessary string conversions. They're error-prone and can be performance bottlenecks too.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
a.CreationDate.ToString("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") == DateTime.Now.ToString("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")
```

with

```
a.CreationDate.Date == DateTime.Today
```